# Pjsip call not disconnects when any one side goes out of network coverage

Tags: android, voip, pjsip, pjsua2

I am able to make calls, if anyone sides whether call initiator or receiver goes out of network coverage that time no voice packets transferring is possible, in fact when anyone side get reconnects the network, again call gets reconnects successfully.

But biggest problem now I am facing is when anyone end goes out of network for more than specified time then both call should disconnect automatically is there any possible way to handle such a scenario?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Look into SIP session timers feature configuration. Or (I prefer this for  interoperability) disconnect if there is no RTP traffic or connection state does not change for a long time (depending on call state media session may not exist or be deactivated with mute, so checking just RTP may be not sufficient).